# Slow Query using where DateTime <>variable

Tags: sql-server

I am currently having a problem with one of my queries. I am extracting 4 columns from a large table. These 4 tables are being saved into a table variable. The query works fine, but the run time is problematic. When I hard code the first date condition, it runs perfectly (about 1-2 sec). When I use a variable instead of a hard-coded date, the query takes about 3.5 minutes to run.

I am running MS SQL Server 2003 with this query.

Would anyone know what's causing this difference in run time?

```
INSERT INTO @TableVariable
SELECT         Coulmn1, Column2, Column3, Column4
FROM           DatabaseTable

/*This line works almost instantaneously)*/

WHERE        (DateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-06-23 00:00:00', 102)) AND (DateTime <= @WeekEndTime)

/*If I use this one, it executes in around 3.5 min and I get the same results*/

WHERE        (DateTime > @WeekStartTime) AND (DateTime < @WeekEndTime)

/*The same slow run time is seen with these lines*/

Declare @testTime varchar(20)

Set @testTime = '2014-06-23 00:00:00'

WHERE        (DateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @testTime , 102)) AND (DateTime <= @WeekEndTime)


/*This line is always used*/

GROUP BY column 1
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a secondary non-clustered index on DateTime?

Comment: Maybe you should ask whoever wrote that SQL Server, because we all have never seen a 2003 version. MS published a 7.0, then 2000, then 2005, then 2008. But no 2003.

Comment: What are the data types of `DateTime` and the various variables in your queries?

Comment: SQL Server can create different execution plans when using variables vs hard coded values.  Did you check the execution plans of the two different queries?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can create different execution plans when using variables vs hard coded values.  if you look at the actual execution plans after running each query you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable @WeekStartTime of the data type DATETIME or String ?   I had a similar situation and when I changed the variable to the data type of DATETIME, things got a whole lot better.  I noticed you are also trying varchar . . . give DATETIME a shot.